# PHP image manipulation

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I have icon which has a blue background and red foreground.

I need to copy this icon, replace the blue background with a transparent background, then change the red for whatever the user has selected.

This image would then be saved in the relevant directory.

The good news is I can do the final step. Unfortunately I have no idea where to start with the rest. Could someone point me in the right direction please. Maybe a list of functions which I would need to use in order so I can look them up and write it.

That or if anyone knows of a simple library that already does this, please recommend!

Thanks.

Comment: As I said above, I just want someone to point me in the right direction or link to a decent library that could do this. I am not asking someone to code it for me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do image manipulation using PHP GD library. A whole lot of sample code and [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is available on the PHP site.

Answer (score 0):

Try quite powerful and easy to use library based on GD2: [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)